# A question about perturbation method of

Tags: perturbation-theory

We consider the differential equation

$ \epsilon y’’+ 2yy’ -4xy =0  $

With boundary condition 
$ y(0)=-1 $, $ y(1)=2$

How could we find the inner solution at $x$ nears $0$? Because if $y(0)$ changes a little, I could show that it is a boundary layer or interior layer; However at this exact $y(0)=-1$ I can't match with the outer solution successfully.

Comment: This question should help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1546644/131807

Comment: You should perhaps indicate what you found as inner and outer solution and that the result should be something like $y(x)=\tanh((x-c(ϵ))/ϵ)+x^2$ and the fitting problem is to derive the form of $c(ϵ)$ from the equation.